# Firebase - getting the download URL (Firebase Storage) and saving it in Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to make something which just uploads a project to Firebase and all.. I cant really explain the project but what I am trying to do is:

1. Get the Firebase download URL when uploading the file.
2. Save it in the Firebase realtime database.

The code I have made for it is:

```
    let downloadURL;
    var filename = filenamechosen;
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/dav' + 'projects' + '/' + filename);
    var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile);

    uploadTask.on("state_changed", function(snapshot){

    }, function(error){

    }, function(){
        console.log(uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
    });
    };

function uploadOne(){
    let projectinf = document.getElementById("projectinfo").value;
    let name = document.getElementById("studentname").value;
    let cls = document.getElementById("cls").value;
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let projectlnk = downloadURL;
    let marks = document.getElementById("marks").value;
    let submitfrm = document.getElementById("submitfrm");
    let studentObj = {
        class: cls,
        email: email, 
        projectinfo: projectinf,
        projectlink: projectlnk,
        marks: "lol",
    }
    firebase.database().ref('/schools/dav/').child(`${name}`).set(studentObj).then().catch();
    console.log("done");
}
```

For getting the download url, I am getting something like this as a response:

```
jt {a: 0, i: undefined, c: jt, b: null, f: null, …}
a: 2
b: null
c: null
f: null
g: false
h: false
i: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/workspace-c7042.appspot.com/o/davproject.... //Continues
```

I have no idea how I can store it in the Firebase realtime database after getting the download URL:

```
<form action="uploadOne()">
<!--Some inputs as defined in the uploadOne function.-->
<button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

This is almost the whole form I am using with that thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#get-downloadurl) method is **asynchronous** and returns a Promise which resolves with the downloadURL.

You therefore need to do something along these lines, using the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method to wait that the Promise resolves:

```
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
```

---

It is not clear in your code how the two different parts are linked (which one calls which and how the file is selected), but one possibility is shown below:

```
let downloadURL;
var filename = filenamechosen;
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/dav' + 'projects' + '/' + filename);
var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile);

uploadTask.on("state_changed",
null,  /// <- See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on
null,
function(){
   // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
    .then(function(downloadURL) {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        uploadOne(downloadURL);  // <- We call the uploadOne function passing the downloadURL as parameter
    });
});


function uploadOne(downloadURL){
    let projectinf = document.getElementById("projectinfo").value;
    let name = document.getElementById("studentname").value;
    let cls = document.getElementById("cls").value;
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let projectlnk = downloadURL;
    let marks = document.getElementById("marks").value;
    let submitfrm = document.getElementById("submitfrm");
    let studentObj = {
        class: cls,
        email: email, 
        projectinfo: projectinf,
        projectlink: projectlnk,
        marks: "lol",
    }
    firebase.database().ref('/schools/dav/').child(`${name}`).set(studentObj)
    .then(function() {
        console.log("done");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

This way it is the `uploadTask` that triggers the write to the database. You can adapt as necessary but in any case you will only get the value of the `downloadURL` in the callback function called when the Promise is fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem!

Comment: Hey that worked but I want to modify it so that it uploads when uploadOne function is triggered. As you can see uploadOne is triggered on form submit. Any ideas on how can I upload it once that function is triggered?